# How to enforce integrity when joined tables share a foreign key?

Tags: database-design

Consider the following table structure:

```
UserGroup(ie. 'Admin')
    ID = 'Admin'
    ApplicationFK = 'App1'

JoinTable
    UserGroupFK = 'Admin'
    PermissionFK = 'Approve'
    PermissionValue = 'READ'

Permission(ie. 'Approve')
    ID = 'Approve'
    ApplicationFK = 'App2'

UserPermission
    UserFK = 'John'
    PermissionFK = 'Approve'
    PermissionValue = 'WRITE'

User
    ID = 'John'
```

Where you have a jointable between UserGroup and Permission, with both UserGroup and Permission having foreign keys to Application.

Is there any way to enforce integrity, to avoid the situation above, where the ApplicationFKs don't match? I cannot simply remove one of the Foreign Keys, as it is possible to have a Permission without any UserGroups, and possible to have a UserGroup without any permissions.

Comment: Yes, I call this the "diamond" problem. Check any of these questions/answers: [diamond](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A993+diamond)

Comment: The "trick" is to add `ApplicationFK` to the lowest table in the diamond (`JoinTable` in this case) and modify the Foreign Key and Unique constraints accordingly.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I've added additional information about related tables I'd previously thought unnecessary. I've also created an answer, attempting to confirm I've correctly understood your suggestion - is it correct?

Comment: No, it doesn't look what I has thinking of. I'll add an answer later tonight.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Updated below answer after some more thought.

Comment: Yes, this more like it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure I understand/have correctly elaborated on @ypercubeᵀᴹ's comment/linked answer:

The correct structure should be:

```
UserGroup(ie. 'Admin')
    ID = 'Admin'
    ApplicationFK = 'App1'
    [PK: ID, ApplicationFK]

JoinTable
    UserGroupFK = 'Admin'
    ApplicationFK = 'App1'
    PermissionFK = 'Approve'
    PermissionValue = 'READ'
    [PK: UserGroupFK, ApplicationFK, PermissionFK]
    [FK -> UserGroupFK+ApplicationFK -> UserGroup]
    [FK -> PermissionFK+ApplicationFK -> Permission]

Permission(ie. 'Approve')
    ID = 'Approve'
    ApplicationFK = 'App1'
    [PK: ID, ApplicationFK]

UserPermission
    UserFK = 'John'
    PermissionFK = 'Approve'
    ApplicationFK = 'App1'
    PermissionValue = 'WRITE'
    [FK -> PermissionFK+ApplicationFK -> Permission]

User
    ID = 'John'
```

Comment: The row you show in `JoinTable` would be invalid, as you don't show a `Permission` row `('Approve','App1')`

Comment: Also - Wherever you're tying to `Permission`, you need to provide the full key: the permission ID and the application ID. The only real difference between `UserPermission` and `JoinTable` is one should assign permissions for an application to a user, and the other to a user group.

Answer (score 0):

The question will be solved after you define primary keys correctly.

Please remember that FK must point to other table's primary key (or unique key).

It is legal (at least in SQL) to use multi-field FKs.